# Get path of Specific file from SD Card

Tags: android-sdcard

I know there are lots of questions and answers discussing this question but I am not finding a proper answer for it.

I have file in sdcard name **database.db**. I want to get path of file. File stored at **mnt/sdcard/db/database.db**. I need output like this **mnt/sdcard/db/** Please help me any code or example will be appreciated

I have only filename then is it possible to get the path from it?

Comment: sorry for spelling and grammer mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT again ^-^:

I think i finally understood what you want to do:  having only a filename as the input, you want to search the whole sd card for it, and if it is present, you want to obtain the path of the directory in which it is in.

Bear in mind that a full search for a file might be slow if user's SD-card contains a lot of folders and files.

Here is a simple function to search for a file:

```
public static void findFilePath(File dir, String filename, List<String> result) {

    // get all files in dir
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for( File f : files ){
        if( f.isDirectory() ){
            // Recurse
            findFilePath(dir, filename, result);
        }

        else{
            if( f.getName().equals("filename") ){
                String absPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
                result.add(absPath.substring(0, absPath.lastIndexOf(File.separator)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
findFilePath( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "database.db", result);

System.out.println(result.get(0));
```

Now, you have a couple of possible issues:

1. There might be more than once directory that contains the file you are searching
2. The search could be arbitrarily slow if the file system is not indexed (which i don't think it is), and if the number of files and directories is big.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that. But I don't need it. I need a method or something in which I can parse filename and it return path of file

Comment: opps sorry for wrong post. It did not work. I put the **database.db** into **mnt/sdcard/db/database.db** but it returns only **mnt/sdcard**

Comment: By doing that, did you replace "database.db" with "db\database.db"?
Or you maybe want to SEARCH the whole SD card for the file you specify? Was that your question?

Comment: Sorry I am edit my question. In my application user have to put database.db file into folder. I want to compare the path form actual to user selected path

Comment: Sorry Lake for misunderstanding

Comment: Does the user specify through your application the folder s/he uses, or s/he will just put the file in an arbitrary folder and you have to search for it? ^^

Comment: No user not specify folder. In simple word user enter filename (database.db) and he get the path of the file in sd card

Comment: So you want to implement a search for a file, is that correct? ^^

Comment: Lake can you help me ?

Comment: Edited again, check it out^^